# MVVM and asynchronous data access

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, system.reactive, caliburn.micro

So I have a WPF application using the MVVM pattern (Caliburn.Micro). I got the views and view-models wired up and basicly what is missing is the data. The data is to be retrieved "on-demand" either from a WCF service, local storage or from memory/cache - reason being to allow for offline-mode and to avoid uneccessary server communication. Another requirement is that the data is retrieved asynchronously so the UI thread is not blocked.

So I was thinking to create some kind of "AssetManager" that the viewmodels use to request data:

```
_someAssetManager.GetSomeSpecificAsset(assetId, OnGetSomeSpecificAssetCompleted)
```

Note that it is an asynchronous call. I run into a few different problems though. If the same asset is requested at (roughly) the same time by different view-models, how do we ensure that we don't do unecessary work and that they both get the same objects that we can bind against?

Not sure I'm having the right approach. I've been glancing a bit at Reactive Framework - but I have no idea how to use it in this scenario. Any suggestions on framework/techniques/patterns that I can use? This seems to be a rather common scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dictionary<int, IObservable<IAsset>> inflightRequests;

public IObservable<IAsset> GetSomeAsset(int id)
{
    // People who ask for an inflight request just get the
    // existing one
    lock(inflightRequests) {
        if inflightRequests.ContainsKey(id) {
            return inflightRequests[id];
        }
    }

    // Create a new IObservable and put in the dictionary
    lock(inflightRequests) { inflightRequests[id] = ret; }

    // Actually do the request and "play it" onto the Subject. 
    var ret = new AsyncSubject<IAsset>();
    GetSomeAssetForReals(id, result => {
        ret.OnNext(id);
        ret.OnCompleted();

        // We're not inflight anymore, remove the item
        lock(inflightRequests) { inflightRequests.Remove(id); }
    })

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Now the first guy to ask for id 5 gets a real request and everyone else who asks in quick succession listen to the same request.

Comment: The even more clever thing is, if you don't actually remove the item from the dictionary, it'll *never* need to request the resource again. I didn't do this though because it's a memory leak (i.e. that dictionary just gets bigger and bigger), and encoding some sort of MRU cache policy would make this sample less illustrative :)

Comment: Nice. Could you not call OnCompleted()? I'm thinking so you can also update the values by calling OnNext(newValue) - so if I subscribe GetAsset(id).Subscribe(x => DoWork());, DoWork is called whenever the asset is updated somewhere.

Comment: BehaviorSubject seems to be what I want in that case. ^^

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with method calls that pass in a delegate that gets called when the data is received.  You could layer the requirement of keeping everyone with the same data (if a request is currently happening) by checking a boolean field that determines if a request is happening.  I would keep a local collection of delegates that need calling so that when the data is finally received, the class that contains the delegates to call can iterate them, passing in the newly received data.

Something along these lines:

```
public interface IViewModelDataLoader{
    void LoadData(AssignData callback);
}

public delegate void AssignData(IEnumerable<DataObject> results);
```

The class that actually implements this interface could then keep a running tally on who to notify when the data is done (assuming a singleton model):

```
public class ViewModelDataLoader : IViewModelDataLoader{
    private IList<AssignData> callbacksToCall;
    private bool isLoading;

    public void LoadData(AssignData callback){
        callbacksToCall.add(callback);
        if (isLoading) { return; }

        // Do some long running code here
        var data = something;
        // Now iterate the list
        foreach(var item in callbacksToCall){
           item(data);
        }
        isLoading = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried something very similar. I gave up when trying to use Monitor.TryEnter(obj) to ensure thread-safety (never got it to work). Maybe I'll give it another try.

Comment: @Pking maybe try `lock(){ }` construct.. I've a bit of code typed up for this question, but it's incomplete..

Answer (score 1):

Using the proxy pattern and events you can provide both synchronous and asynchronous data. Have your proxy returned cached values for synchronous calls and also notify view models via events when your receive asynchronous data. The proxy can also be designed to track data requests and throttle server connections (eg 'reference counting' calls, data requested/data received flags, etc)

Comment: Interresting, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I would set up you `AssetManager` like this:

```
public interface IAssetManager
{
    IObservable<IAsset> GetSomeSpecificAsset(int assetId);
}
```

Internally you would need to return a `Subject<IAsset>` that you populate asynchronously. Do it right and you only have a single call for each call to `GetSomeSpecificAsset`.